# Where is the Nightmare's key in Catfish's Maw?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I have completed everything I can think of, and my map shows no more rooms with Chests in, yet I do not have the Nightmare's key.

Where is it in this dungeon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - So whether you decided to fight gohma or not, backtrack down a screen, right, and up two screens to get back to where we first fought
>     master stalfos. Continue right a screen and you’ll see a staircase
>     here. If we head down this staircase at this point in time and go
>     through the underground sequence, we will resurface and nearby we’ll
>     find an owl statue that states, “Dive under where torchlight beams do
>     cross…” The rest of the area leads to the same dead end that the
>     stairs by Gohma led to. So, backtrack to the room just to the right of
>     where we first fought Master Stalfos.
>
>   - From here walk up a screen and push the central block once again before heading left a screen. Defeat or avoid the enemies and head up
>       a screen. Defeat the four water tektites found in this room and then
>       if you look at the walls, you’ll see four torchlights. If you were to
>       connect the ones on opposite sides with lines, they’ll meet right in
>       the center of the deep water. So just as the owl statue stated, let’s
>       dive underneath.
>   - Make your way through this underwater area, defeating enemy bloopers along the way. These are another example of Mario enemies
>       found within this title. Resurface on the next screen to find yourself
>       in a new part of the dungeon. Use the hook shot to grab onto the latch
>       and extend a bridge across. Walk over to the treasure chest and open
>       it to get the Nightmare’s Key. Backtrack through the underwater area.

[Map Here](http://www.zeldawiki.org/images/8/89/Catfish%27s_Maw_Map.png)

[image][image]

Comment: Boo. That's irritating. But yay, I have a key now. :)

Comment: I didnt know if you understood what I meant so there is a more elaborate description :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the room with four Water Tekites. Destroy them, dive in the dark blue water, and do the rest to get the nightmare key.